# Filtering R package example datasets by class

Tags: r

I am testing some techniques for detecting out of control time series data using shiny to compare and contrast different techniques and settings.

As testing data, I would like to obtain all example datasets included in the package `surveilance` and filter those datasets so that I only have the names of those which are of class `sts` (surveillance time series). I would then like to have a `selectInput` populated with the names of the filtered datasets, and set a variable to point to the dataset named by the selected string (equating to the dataset name). Something like this `R` code:

```r
d <- data(package = "surveillance")
r <- d$results[, "Item"]
r <- r[class(??what here??) == "sts"]
...
.data <- data(input$dataset) # this won't work because input$dataset is of type character
```

Will you please help me work out how to filter the dataset names and subsequently assign to a variable based on the string value of the dataset name.

Comment: Maybe `sapply(r,function(x)class(disProg2sts(x))[1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way loading data sets work is a bit awkward. Here's a helper function to pull the data class. I've used the helper function to load the dataset into a private environment rather than the global environment which is the default.

```
d <- data(package = "surveillance")
r <- d$results[, "Item"]

check_data_class <- function(x, package=package) {
  env <- new.env()
  nm <- data(list=x, package=package, envir=env)
  class(env[[nm]])
}

cls <- sapply(r, check_data_class, package="surveillance")
names(cls[cls=="sts"])
#  [1] "abattoir"         "deleval"          "fluBYBW"         
#  [4] "ha.sts"           "measlesDE"        "measlesWeserEms" 
#  [7] "momo"             "rotaBB"           "salmAllOnset"    
# [10] "salmHospitalized" "salmNewport"      "stsNewport"
```

These are all the data objects that have a class of "sts".

The key part to getting a dataset via a string name is using the `list=` parameter to `data()`. And note that `data()` doens't actually return the data itself. It loads the data into the global environment with it's given name.